# Woocommerce Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I have a custom wordpress theme that I am developing with the use of the woocommerce plugin.

It is built using twitter bootstrap and the carousel and other jquery dependent things work just fine. However, it looks like anything to do with jquery that is specific to the  woocommerce plugin such as the tabs aren't working.

I uploaded the site so you can see how the tabs aren't working here :
http://www.caimanmedia.com/rjipublishing/shop/on-the-raft/

I am calling jQuery in my functions.php file like this:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // initiate the function  
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/library/js/libs/jquery.1.9.1.min.js', false, '1.9.1');
```

I am wondering if there is a conflict between the two? I am not sure why the woocommerce jquery portion isn't working but the twitter bootstrap part is.

When I look at my source code, I see this on line 56:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.caimanmedia.com/rjipublishing/wp-content/themes/rjipublishing/library/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?ver=1.9.1'></script>
```

and then on line 79 I see this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering if I need to disable one? If so, which one would I disable?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using jQuery bundled with WordPress and disabling the  lines that include other jQuery. Please refer to http://www.mojowill.com/developer/using-javascript-with-wordpress-correctly/ for more detail.

Comment: Thank you I will try it and post my results!